# Ionic Cordova resources Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Trying to use ionic cordova resources ios to generate me a splashscreen and icon.  When I run, I get Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Searched SO

ionic cordova resources ios

Answer (score 0):

I found in my case that, as I operate on a quite restricted network (I work in a school) the school internet server was blocking access to the Ionic resources service.  So tethering temporarily from my iPhone allowed me to complete this, after which I jumped back on the normal network.
Hope this might save someone else some time, as it cost me a lot of time chasing this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the next command prior cordoba install

npm set strict-ssl false